# Iterate JSON object with jquery

Tags: jquery, json

Why isn't the following working, inside a loop it never prints the url when myJSON is empty or not.

```
$.each($.parseJSON(myJSON), function(key,value){
    alert(value.url);
});
```

for this JSON structure:

```
[{"host":"foo","url":"bar"},{"host":"foos","url":"bars"}]
```

Edit: $.each is inside a loop which has instances/iterations where myJSON is empty if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This works for me.

```
var myJSON = '[{"host":"foo","url":"bar"},{"host":"foos","url":"bars"}]';

$.each($.parseJSON(myJSON), function(key,value){
    alert(value.url);
});
```

Answer (score 9):

```
var data = [{"host":"foo","url":"bar"},{"host":"foos","url":"bars"}]

$.each(data, function(i, item) {
    alert(data[i].host);
});​
```

same as with the url.

Comment: Even though I used JSON.stringify on myJSON?

Comment: are you sending the JSON from some server side code or just through client side.

Comment: myJSON is being prepared to be sent to server.

Comment: have u set the MIME stype...for e.g response.setContentType("application/json");
 on server side.

Comment: Anyway, I've put a condition to only do $.each if myJSON is not empty and it's working now.